# Postgres concatenate regex and table column

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, concatenation

I would like to run the query

```
SELECT * FROM table_a JOIN table_b ON table_a.title LIKE ('^[a-b]' || table_b.title)
```

where if table_a.title = "the foo bar", and table_b.title has a row named "oo", the query will not return any results, but if table_b.title has a row named "foo", it will return results.

Basically I want to match the title on table_b only if it is an entire word (surrounded by spaces, or at the beginning and end of string) but not if another word has a part of table_b.title in it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add some sample data and your expected results ;).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expressions in Postgres, use `~`, `similar to`, or `regexp_matches`, not `like`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a JOIN
     table_b
     ON table_a.title ~ ('^[a-b]' || table_b.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
SELECT 1 FROM table_a JOIN table_b 
ON (' ' || table_b.title || ' ') ~* ('.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9]+' || table_b.name || '[^a-zA-Z0-9].*?') 
where table_b.id IS NOT NULL
```